# Crear grafico de tipo campana poblacionar a partir de dos dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

dispongo de dos dataframes que compartirian los valores de un eje, y para hacer más visible el resultado querria contraponerlos de manera que quedasen uno frente al otro como pasa con las pirámides poblacionales, sin embargo no consigo hacerlo. Mi idea es crear un subplot con 2 columnas y compartir el eje y pero estoy teniendo errores ya que la tabla que pretendo representar tiene varios valores para cada eje, es decir a aparecerian contrapuestos los valores de varios años por cada valor de la escala del eje compartido. Los dataframes de que dispongo son los siguientes, añadidos a un link de drive, los dos archivos en la carpeta [Enlace a Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gj8U50wJqGCPgTvtUdLH0CdHo6HuDmbL?usp=sharing).
Por si algo fallase aquí adjunto imagenes de ambos dataframes:

[image: Primer Dataframe]

[image: segundo dataframe]

La diferencia en lo que respecta al eje horizontal de la tabla es consecuencia de haber aplicado en un caso reset_index(), en el dataframe en formato csv ya ha sido aplicado a ambos y la columna years, por algun motivo toma ese nombre de manera residual pero corresponde al index.
El gráfico que estoy buscando es algo del siguiente tipo:
[image: Tipo de grafico]

Solo que en mi caso deberian aparecer por cada una de las barras horizontales las 4 correspondientes una a cada año.

Mi código actual es el siguiente:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols = 2, sharey = True)
ax[0].barh(dias_flota['camion'], dflota[2017], align = 'center')
ax[1].barh(dt['camion'], dflota[2017],align = 'center')
ax[0].invert_xaxis()
```

de esta manera obtengo los dos gráficos enfrentados pero tan solo me permite emplear como eje y los valores de un solo dato de años y debería ser de todos los años con una grafica semejante a esta:

[image: Grafica deseada para la mitad]

solo que el resultado final deberían ser 2 graficas de este tipo contrapuestas mientras que lo que obtengo es lo siguiente:

[image: grafico de campana]

Mi intención es que en el eje y aparezcan en ambos lados, derecho e izquierdo a parte de la escala las 4 barras correspondientes a años y el conflicto concreto que solo logro que se imprima un solo año, ya que el valor y de la grafica solo me permite introducir una lista.

Comment: Hola @dpm24, no he entendido muy bien los requisitos, cuáles valores usaste como 'x' ,'y', en la gráfica. Por favor adjunta el código que estas intentando probar, para intentar entender mejor dónde puede estar el error entre lo que buscar y la representación obtenida.

Comment: Buenas @Eli-js los valores que uso como X e Y respectivamente son los que adjunto en el enlace a Drive, ahi estan los archivos csv con los dos dataframes, el grafico no sale de ningún lado,es un mero ejemplo del resultado que quiero obtener a partir de los datos que tengo en esos dos csv.

Comment: Hola @dpm24, para lo que entiendo que quieres hacer, lo primero es ajustar la 'forma' de tus datos de modo que tengas en una estructura más adecuada para representar (ejm: `year,TotalCamiones, counterFichero1, counterFichero2`). Para usarlos de manera apropiada, puedes revisar esta [guía](https://mharias.com/2017/08/24/352/). Lamento darte este comentario tan genérico, pero sin un código de referencia con lo que estás intentando, o donde tienes los errores de representación, es muy difícil ser más específica en la solución. Un saludo.

Comment: @Eli-js gracias por tu comentario, voy a modificar la pregunta añadiendo lo que tengo de código actualmente para intentar reflejar mejor la duda.

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener una gráfica segmentada por año como la imagen que adjuntas, puedes hacer lo siguiente (ejemplo usando tu primer conjunto de datos):

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv('primer_dataframe.csv', sep=',', index_col=0)
```

Reorganizamos los datos:

```
df1 = pd.melt(df1, id_vars=["camion"], 
                     var_name="Year", value_name="Value")
```

Al generar el gráfico, el parámetro **`hue`** te permite indicar el atributo por el que quieres segmentar, en este caso por la columna `'Year'`:

```
import seaborn as sns

df1["camion"] = df1["camion"].astype('category')
sns.catplot(y = "camion", x = "Value", kind = "bar", data = df1, hue = "Year")
```

Y esta seria la gráfica usando tu primer conjunto de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No conseguí reproducir el ejemplo a partir del código que incluyes, no me llega a quedar clara la estructura de tus dataframes (dias_flota, d_flota, dt). Con la reorganización de la estructura del dataframe de entrada y la segmentación por año, entiendo que se resolvería tu problema.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta he conseguido hacer lo que queria empleando tu ejemplo, he tenido que modificar un oar de cosas, escribire una respuesta explicando como lo hice, pero basicamente a cada tabla le he aplicado tu respuesta solo que rotando una de ellas y contraponuendolas a demas de compartir el eje y. Muchas gracias